# Is an object considered an "outside object" even if it's being used in its own class?

Tags: c++, oop

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
class B {
protected:
    int x;

public:
    B(int i = 28) { x = i; }
    virtual B f(B ob) { return x + ob.x + 1; }
    void show() { cout << x; }
};
class D : public B {
public:
    D(int i = -32)
        : B(i)
    {
    }
    B f(B ob) { return x + ob.x - 1; } //line 19
};
int main()
{
    B *p1 = new D, *p2 = new B, *p3 = new B(p1->f(*p2));
    p3->show();
    return 0;
}
```

The compiler error:

```
(line 19) int B::x is protected within this context, declared protected
```

I'm trying to understand why ob shows up as protected even though I'm using it in its own class. Are all objects excluding 'this' subject to being private/protected? Sorry for poor wording. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Guessing, is line 19 the line `B f(B ob) ...`? The problem is that member functions of a class can access protected members of the object that they are being called on, but they cannot access protected members of other objects. So `x` in that line is okay, but `b.x` is not.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access

Comment: @PeteBecker I never knew that. `protected` is truly a bizarre modifier.

Comment: I've forgotten the details, but there is a corner case where allowing access to `b.x` can break encapsulation.

Comment: *"why ob shows up as protected even though I'm using it in its own class."* -- On line 19, the class of `ob` is `B`, but line 19 is not part of `B`. So how do you get that you are using `ob` in its own class?

Comment: @PeteBecker *"they cannot access protected members of other objects."* -- almost. They can access protected members of other objects when that other object is of the same type. Inside `D::f()`, it is OK to access `D::x`, but not `B::x`. If the parameter type was changed from `B` to `D`, the class would compile.

Answer (score 5):

From [cppreference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/access) on "Protected Member Access" (emphasis mine)

> A protected member of a class is only accessible
>
> 1. to the members and friends of that class;
> 2. to the members and friends (until C++17) of any derived class of that class, but **only when the class of the object through which the protected member is accessed is that derived class or a derived class of that derived class**

So subclasses cannot access `protected` members of *other* instances of the parent class.

Answer (score 1):

Your intuition might be better if you think about the case where there is more than one derived class. Here is an example where there are two derived classes, each with different ideas of how the protected member (`x`) should be used. (Pretend there are other members that have been omitted for simplicity.)

```cpp
class Base {
  protected:
    // Base will reset x to zero under certain circumstances.
    // Otherwise, it is for derived classes to use.
    int x = 0;
};

struct Derived : public Base {
    // Derived chooses to use negative values for x.
    Derived() : Base() { x--; }
    void update(Derived& other) {
        other.x = x;
    }
};

struct Alternative : public Base {
    // Alternative chooses to use positive values for x.
    Alternative() : Base() { x++; }
    void update(Alternative& other) {
        other.x = x;
    }
};
```

This much is good. It compiles, because unlike the question's code, `Derived` accesses `x` only in `Derived` objects, not in `Base` objects. `Derived` objects never have a positive `x`, and `Alternative` objects never have a negative `x`.

What happens if we change the type of `update`'s parameter to `Base&`? Compilation fails, as in the question. Why? Well, you do not want a situation like the following:

```cpp
    Derived negative;
    Alternative positive;
    negative.update(positive); // <-- problem!
```

If `Derived::update()` were to accept a `Base&` instead of a `Derived&`, then  the above would also compile. An object can be converted to a reference to an unambiguous base class, so `positive` would be an acceptable argument. However, `update` would proceed to set `positive.x` to `negative.x`, breaking the assumption `Alternative` makes about `x` never being negative. Breaking another class is Bad.

This example is contrived for simplicity. yet the principle is there. Sibling classes are not friends; they often are not even aware of each other's existence. A class cannot be allowed to mess with a different class. Even though a derived class might have some protected access to its base, it can only do so when it is known that the object in question is actually the same class, not some other derived class.